# services are not included in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, angularjs-factory

I have integrated requirejs with angularjs app.
Now I am getting errror `'Provider commonService must define $get factory method. from myApp '`

How can i include services with requirejs ?
Here I am posting serviceConfig code :

```
define([
    'angular',
    'Services/services',
    'Plugins/Users/services',
], function(angular, commonService,usersServices) {
    var services = {
        commonService : commonService,
        usersServices : usersServices,
    };

    var initialize = function (angModule) {
        angular.forEach(services,function(service, name) {
            angModule.factory(name, service);
        });
    }

    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
})
```

'Services/services' and 'Plugins/Users/services' contains differenrt services in it.
eg.

```
define(['angular'], function (angular) {
    app = angular.module(appName + '.services', []);

    app.factory('usersService', function($http, $q, $rootScope) {
           function usersService() {
                 this.registration = function(config) {
                     return this.common(config);
                 };
           }
          return new usersService();
       });
});
```

What is wrong here ?

Comment: eesh. why cramming angular into AMD? Better for server to just compile down to one file anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to register the service twice. In your service definition 'Services/services' you create a module 'myApp.services' and register the service.

You don't need to register them again in serviceConfig/initialize.
Then you only need to reference these module when creating your main module ('myApp' I presume) like this:

```
app = angular.module("myApp", ["myApp.services", "myApp.plugin.services"]);
```

Note that you still need to require serviceConfig beforehand, so the modules get registered with angular.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error message from angular-gravar: ""Provider gravatarService must define $get factory method."

I fixed by editing the code to do `provider('gravatarService', function() { … }` instead of `provider('gravatarService', [ function() { … } ]`.

That was on Angular 1.02; I've since upgraded to 1.2.16 and then it works fine with the wrapping array.